# Update UI from data gathered in a LAN thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, user-interface

I have a thread that looks at the LAN and gathers data used to update a ListView.
Problem is that I cannot update ListView from a thread other than the UI.
The user pressed a key which fires off a query to a server on the LAN, then expects a ListView to show the data.
What's the best way to do this LAN monitoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would want something like this:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateUI();
    }
};

private void getLAN() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //do LAN stuff
            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

private void updateUI() {
    //update UI
}
```

Comment: Couple of questions: mHandler.post(mHandler.post(mUpdateResults); can this be executed from inside a forever loop? and do I have to cast mUpdateResults ?

Comment: I basically pulled this out of my own code so no casting needing. As for the loop, I haven't tried it myself but I don't see why not, worth a try at least!